# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I use pretreatment sql
There was no error when using JDBC Driver version 9.2.0.8.0(classes12.jar) However, this happens only after upgrading to version 9.2.0.8.0 later.
error code is Missing IN or OUT parameter at index

Below is my code.

```
BEGIN
   SELECT sysdate
   INTO   :today
   FROM   dual;

   BEGIN
      SELECT sysdate
      INTO   :today2
      FROM   dual;
  EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         :today2 := NULL;
   END;

   SELECT sysdate
   INTO   :today4
   FROM   dual;
END;
```

My question is, can't use EXCEPTION, sql? or are there other solutions available for A?

My JSP File

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=euc-kr"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*"%><%!private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    private DatabaseMetaData meta;

    //*********************************************************************************
    // 여기에 DB정보를 적어 주십시오.
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.10.38:1521:ora920";
    public static final String DRIVER_NAME = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    public static final String ID = "scott";
    public static final String PW = "tiger";

    //*********************************************************************************

    public void jspInit()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, ID, PW);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
        {
            //getServletContext().log( "Error: Database Driver Class : " + DB_CLASS_NMAE );
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            //getServletContext().log( "Error: DB Connection Error : " + ioe );
        }
    }

    public void jspDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            //getServletContext().log( "Error: Server Write  Exception : " + ioe);
        }
    }%>
<%
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, ID, PW);

    ResultSet empCursor = null;
    try
    {
        //pstmt = rdconn.prepareStatement(query);
        //stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        meta = conn.getMetaData();

        out.println("JDBC Driver Information<br>");
        out.println("---------------------------------<br>");
        out.println("version; " + meta.getDriverVersion() + "<br>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Database Information<br>");
        out.println("---------------------------------<br>");
        out.println("database name; " + meta.getDatabaseProductName() + "<br>");
        out.println("version; " + meta.getDatabaseProductVersion() + "<br>");
        out.println("<br>");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(toHangle("Error occurred<br>") + toHangle(e.toString()));
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    out.println("---------------------------------<br>");
    out.println("Pretreatment test<br>");
    out.println("---------------------------------<br>");
    // 전처리 테스트
    StringBuilder plsql = new StringBuilder();
    plsql.append("BEGIN\n");
    plsql.append("   SELECT sysdate\n");
    plsql.append("      INTO   :today1\n"); // 첫 번째 Parameter
    plsql.append("      FROM   dual;\n");
    plsql.append("   BEGIN\n");
    plsql.append("      SELECT sysdate\n");
    plsql.append("         INTO   :today2\n"); // 두 번째 Parameter
    plsql.append("         FROM   dual;\n");
    // 에러 발생 원인은 EXCEPTION 안 parameter를 사용하는 경우
    plsql.append("   EXCEPTION\n");
    plsql.append("      WHEN OTHERS THEN\n");
    plsql.append("         :today2 := NULL;\n"); // 두 번째 Parameter
    //
    plsql.append("   END;\n");
    plsql.append("      SELECT sysdate\n");
    plsql.append("         INTO   :today3\n"); // 세 번째 Parameter
    plsql.append("         FROM   dual;\n");
    plsql.append("END;\n");

    out.println("<pre>" + plsql.toString() + "</pre>");

    try
    {
        out.println("CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall()<br>");
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(plsql.toString());

        // today1~3 갯수에 맞게 3개의 OutParameter를 등록
        for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            out.println("cstmt.registerOutParameter(" + j + ", " + Types.CHAR + ")<br>");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(j, Types.CHAR);
        }


        // 최신 Oracle JDBC Driver에서 에러 발생
        out.println("// 최신 Oracle JDBC Driver에서 에러 발생<br>");
        out.println("cstmt.execute()<br>");
        cstmt.execute();
        out.println("<font color=blue>전처리 실행 성공!!</font>");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("<font color=red>전처리 실행 실패!!</font>");
        out.println("<br>---------------------------------<br>");
        out.println("Exection<br>");
        out.println("<pre>");
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
        out.println("</pre>");
    }
%>
<%!private String toHangle(String oldString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        if(oldString != null)
        {
            return new String(oldString.getBytes("KSC5601"), "8859_1");
        }
        else
        {
            return oldString;
        }
    }%>
```

Comment: could you attach your java code?

Comment: @GustiArya thanks uploaded my jsp code

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated driver version? Are you **really** still using Java 1.2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name using driver version is last version so... starting from version 9.2.0.8.0 or later

Comment: The "last" (=latest) version is 12.2.0.1 `classes12.jar` is intended for Java **1.2**. I don't think driver version 9.2.x is even supported. Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to something like this :

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter("today1", Types.CHAR);
cstmt.registerOutParameter("today2", Types.CHAR);
cstmt.registerOutParameter("today3", Types.CHAR);
```